# Selenium - Driver.quit() produces an "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError" after closing webdriver

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I made an API with express in Node. That API has an endpoint, which when called, it executes a method that starts a selenium webdriver instance and fills a form in a webpage. At the end of that method, I try to execute driver.quit() to close the webdriver, but no matter what, I get the same error:

```
(node:18608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: NoSuchSessionError: Tried to run command without establishing a connection
    at Object.throwDecodedError (D:\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:517:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (D:\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:655:13)
    at Executor.execute (D:\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:581:28)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async thenableWebDriverProxy.execute (D:\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:724:17)
    at async thenableWebDriverProxy.findElements (D:\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1020:17)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

**Environment**

- Windows 10
- Node v14.7.0
- selenium-webdriver: 4.0.0-alpha.8
- express: 4.17.1
- Latest version of geckodriver (0.29.0)
- Latest version of Firefox (85.0)

**What I did**

As per the selenium documentation, I'm using await/async to handle all the promises of the webdriver. Furthermore, I surrounded the execution of the method with a try-catch. Here's a stripped-down version of the main method:

```
let driver;    

module.exports.bot = async function(user, password, var_a, var_b) {
    try {
        await (driver = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(options).build());

        logger("Starting...");
        // Go to main page
        await driver.get("https://www.example.com");
        // Find the dropdown and hover it
        await hoverDropdown();

        const button = await driver.findElement(By.id("j_idt8:j_idt18"));
        await button.click();

        await login(user, password);
        logger("Logged in successfuly");
        await fillForm(var_a, var_b);    

        logger("Finishing...");
    } catch (error) {
        throw error;
    } finally {
        if (driver)
            await driver.quit();           
    }
};
```

After that method finishes executing (event after driver.quit is executed), node crashes with the UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning.

What should I do? Could somebody lend me a hand?

Comment: Which line you are getting error

Comment: @PDHide Well, I really don't know. The error just pops out after everything is executed. Even after express returns a response for the API call. And as you can see in the OP, the message shown doesn't indicate in which line of my code it happens (it shows lines of selenium-webdriver internals).

Comment: could you try removing the throw error command ?

Answer (score 1):

I've discovered the error. I'm going to post it in case someone stumble upons the same (or a similar) issue.

Turns out, I was wrongly using the "wait" method of selenium in my code. The documentation says that "the wait will repeatedly evaluate the condition until it returns a truthy value".

As my syntax was wrong, the wait method never timed out, so it kept looping... even after executing driver.quit();

That's why the error that crashed Node had this line. It was trying to find the element.

```
at async thenableWebDriverProxy.findElements (D:\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\webdriver.js:1020:17)
```

**Incorrect syntax:**

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id("msgError"), 1000));
```

**Correct syntax:**

```
await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id("msgError")), 1000);
```

It's also important to notice that this method throws an exception (timeout exception), so you must try-catch it too.